# Date error importing csv into Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, csv

I am trying to import a csv file that has birthdays and anniversaries in the American format, i.e., MonthDayYear. I found this answer on SO, but it didn't work for me. If I leave off the conversion language, the data imports as YearDayMonth, which is incorrect (and also skips dates where the month is >12.  Here's the code:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  #this is for importing members from csv file
  def self.assign_from_row(row)
    member = Member.where(member_id:   row[:member_id]).first_or_initialize
    member.assign_attributes row.to_hash.slice(
      :member_id, :last_name, :first_name, :email, 
      :anniversary => DateTime.strptime(row[4], "%m/$d/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d"), 
      :birthday => DateTime.strptime(row[5], "%m/$d/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
      )
    member  
    end
  end
```

The error is "ArgumentError at /members/import"

Again, the code works as far as importing, if I delete the

```
=> DateTime.strip ... /%d")
```

but the dates are wrong. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slice` doesn't work the way you have it, you can't provide a hash and values and expect it to merge those in, you want something more like this:

```
member.assign_attributes row.to_hash.slice(
  :member_id,
  :last_name,
  :first_name,
  :email
).merge(
  :anniversary => DateTime.strptime(row[4], "%m/$d/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d"), 
  :birthday => DateTime.strptime(row[5], "%m/$d/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
)
```

Although, I can't say whether `row[4]` or `row[5]` are the right elements, elsewhere you index into that structure using symbols, but the essence here is to use `slice(...).merge(...)` rather than what you have.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, the row was row[:birthday] etc. I struggled a long time with this because of a silly typo! (:/%m/%d/%Y")